# Perl glob range permutations

Tags: perl, range, glob

Need to use Perl in order to create permutations

Need to know if glob allows me to create different permutations based on ranges: numeric or strings
[1..9] or ['a'-'z']

Examples:
perl -le 'print for glob "{L,E,V}{1,2,3,4,5}"'
I want to not manually enter 1,2...5.
Possibilites from 1 to 100 for values L E V

1. L
2. L
3. L
4. L
5. L

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, glob does not do that, unless files with all those names exist.  Only explicitly listed filename parts are returned by glob whether or not the file exists.

But you can use perl to build up the list for you:

```
@list = glob '{L,E,V}{' . join(',', 1..100) . '}';
```

However, since the only real reason to use glob for this is how easy and terse it is, at this point it makes sense to look for non-glob solution.

Here's one:

```
@list = map {
    my $lev = $_;
    map $lev . $_, 1..100;
} qw/L E V/;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're wrong. It seems like you don’t actually know how `glob` **really** works.  `perl -le 'print for glob "{L,E,V}{1,2,3,4,5}"' | wc` produces 15 lines of nonexistent files, just as one would wish.  Best edit your answer so it  isn't misrepresenting the truth, which is the most charitable way I can manage to phrase it.

Comment: @tchrist: you misunderstood me.  glob clearly does assemble and return "explictly listed filename parts", whether the file exists or not, as is shown in the question and in my answer.  But to use a range, as the question requests (something like `glob '{L,E,V}[1-9]'`), such files must exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but if you want to do permutations, see the [Perl FAQ](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How%5Fdo%5FI%5Fpermute%5FN%5Fe).

Answer (score 0):

From [perldoc -f glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

> If non-empty braces are the only
>   wildcard characters used in the glob,
>   no filenames are matched, but
>   potentially many strings are returned.
>   For example, this produces nine
>   strings, one for each pairing of
>   fruits and colors:
>
> 1. @many = glob "{apple,tomato,cherry}={green,yellow,red}";

As you can see, this feature only works with the `{}` metanotation.